# No option for turning off generation of ROW ID Column for SQL Server 2014 in SSMA v5.3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-migration, sql-server-2014, sql-server-migration-assi

i need to turn off the generation of ROW ID column that SSMA generates automatically in SQL Server 2014.

This Option can be turned off in SQL Server 2012 and previous versions but not in SQL Server 2014.
Why is this so ? ...
Can i turn it off any way in SQL Server 2014?

The Option for Row ID for SQL Server 2014 is only as follows:

[image: Options For SQL Server 2014]

where as the Option for Row ID for SQL Server 2012 and previous versions is
as follows:

[image: Options For SQL Server 2012]

Please let me Know if there is any way if i can turn off ROW ID generation.

Comment: I don't now why it's so, but notice that v5.3 is not the latest version, they actually released v6.0 (tool has own "blog", found it there - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/ ). And surprisingly switch is shown for SQL Server 2014 mode in v6.0. :) Maybe it's a bug, I'm not affiliated with them for long time and cannot confirm anyway. Don't forget to get the extension pack for v6.0 - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43689 ;)

Comment: @IgorK It has created Errors in all Triggers because i turned off the ROW ID generation. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: It's not related to this Question. Better create a new one with example of source and converted trigger with row id generation enabled (to understand better what it is going to do) - it depends on the type of trigger at least. Most likely it's due to trigger type not supported directly by SQL Server and emulated in some way.

Comment: @IgorK new question created.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979681/generation-of-rowid-column-in-triggers-even-when-its-generation-is-switched-off